# How to compile LLVM .cpp file in Windows

Tags: windows, llvm

I have a file I found on the internet which uses LLVM API, it is supposed to compile with the following command (UNIX):

```
clang++ test-functionpass.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs core` -shared -o test-functionpass.so
```

Is it possible to compile on Windows? I have installed LLVM 3.6, Mingw, cygwin but I have not successfully run this command to compile the file. any idea?

Comment: What's the problem - the backticks? That means substitute the output of that command into this command line. Can you run llvm-config on its own?

Comment: @Rup: I have tried in several ways, in Cygwin: **Alex@Home-PC /cygdrive/c/users/homeadmin/desktop
$ clang++ test-functionpass.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs core` -shared -o test-functionpass.so
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'Files'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: '(x86)\LLVM/include'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: 'Files'
clang++.exe: error: no such file or directory: '(x86)\LLVM/lib'** And yes, I  was able to use the other tools (clang.exe, llc.exe, ect) with simple commands even in cmd.exe (Windows).

Comment: @Rup, it looks like the problems is passing "`llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --libs core`". the backticks? I'm not sure.